# May i save multiple records at a time in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have List of particular class. I want to save this List at a time without loop using Hibernate Transaction. Is it possible ?

Suppose i have a class

```
 Class a{
    private int no;
    private String name;

    public getNo(){
    return this.no;
    }
    public setNo(int no){
    this.no=no;
    }
    public getName(){
    return this.name;
    }
    public setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
    }
}
```

now i have

```
List<a> list;
```

so i can save list directly without looping?
If yes, than please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this without loop

for that you need to use spring's hibernate utility

that utility like

```
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(questionsCollection);
```

or

```
getHibernateTemplate().deleteAll(questionsCollection);
```

Comment: This is good but may i do this in Hibernate and Java only whiout using Spring.

Comment: yes thats right,
but you want to use than you need to add Spring-hibernate.jar in to your project,
you need not to use spring in your project.